# Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found on Laravel production shared server

Tags: laravel, api, composer-php, guzzle, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to retrieve data from an API using Guzzle. I followed the steps in Guzzle website, installed it using composer, added the route and the code in a controller.

I tried these two options:

```php
$client = new Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    // You can set any number of default request options.
    'timeout' => 2.0,
]);
```

and...

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/',
    // You can set any number of default request options.
    'timeout' => 2.0,
]);
```

When running I got the error...

> Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found.

I have tried:

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php');

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

In composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
  ...
},
```

Also...

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
```

The project is on shared hosting; I noticed that there was no Guzzle folder inside the /vendor folder, so I uploaded via FTP. But still the same error.

I've tried everything I found in the forum on this topic; I'm running out of ideas, please any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: Composer install does not help right? Can you do a new laravel app and try to install it there. If that works you got a problem in your current repo. I did just try to do that on my ubuntu machine and ```use GuzzleHttp\Client; $c = new Client;```works fine. Also the folder in vendor should be named "guzzlehttp" - assuming that was a typo. Finally, what is the status of your lockfile?

Comment: Try `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` instead of manually adding it to the file(s). It should show you all the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, at the beginning I tried composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle but the "guzzlehttp" folder wasn´t added to the shared host so had to do it using FTP. The lock file that you mentioned is the composer.lock? Thanks

Comment: I did the process on a local server and it works, the problem is in the shared host. I already have a laravel application deployed on the shared host. I managed to connect the server through SSH but I'm afraid of installing composer and causing damage to the application, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't run `composer` on shared hosting, you should upload also `/vendor/composer` directory (after local `$ composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`).

Comment: You should upload **all** of `vendor` if you can't run Composer on the host.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, you are right, but @AugustoM says specifically there is no Guzzle folder inside the `/vendor`